# How to generate random image with emojis using python

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, captcha

I want to create a image that contains 5 random emojis from emoji list. I know how to create random text captcha using python captcha module but it didn't work with emojis. I want to create image like this

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know. You can use Pillow to render emoji on a picture.

Example:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import emoji

thumbs_up = emoji.emojize(':thumbs_up:')
base_img = Image.open(r'base_image.jpg')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(base_img)
font = ImageFont.truetype('OpenSansEmoji.ttf', 64, encoding='unic')
draw.text(xy=(100, 150), text=thumbs_up, fill=(255, 255, 255), font=font)

base_img.save('base_image_1.jpg')
```

The OpenSansEmoji.ttf is in [here](https://github.com/MorbZ/OpenSansEmoji/blob/master/OpenSansEmoji.ttf).

But that's not a perfect solution. I think rendering emoji as a picture is a better way. Such as `base_img.paste(Image.open(r'emoji.png'))`

Answer (score 0):

For a different use case, I faced the same challenge of pasting emojis into an image. The previous answer by @McKing does not allow to rotate emojis, which is desired in the example of OP. The code below allows for easily pasting multiple emojis into an image and scale/rotate them.

The approach of the code is to convert each emoji into an image by writing it onto an interim image with a transparent background. Subsequently, this interim image is scaled/rotated according to the user input and added to the `base image` at the desired location. Similar to the answer of @McKing, the code translates an "emoji prompt" e.g. `:thumbs_up:` to it's associated emoji.

Note: The emojis which OP used in his example stem from Apple's proprietary `AppleColorEmoji.ttf` font, whose use might cause licensing issues for you, depending on your use case. The code below uses the [`noto-emoji` font](https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-emoji/tree/main), which is available under the [Apache 2.0 license](https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-emoji/blob/main/LICENSE).

Here's an example of how the code below works:

```
from pathlib import Path
from urllib.request import urlopen

from PIL import Image

from emoji_image_creator import EmojiImageCreator

if __name__ == "__main__":

    noto_font_fp = Path().resolve().joinpath("emoji_to_image").joinpath(
        "NotoColorEmoji.ttf")
    emoji_image_creator = EmojiImageCreator(emoji_font_fp=str(noto_font_fp))

    base_image_to_use = Image.open(urlopen("https://placehold.co/600x400.png"))

    base_image_w_emojis = emoji_image_creator.generate_and_add_to_img(
        xy_coords=(50, 50),
        base_image=base_image_to_use,
        emoji_prompt=":thumbs_up:",
        tar_height=75,
        angle=30)

    base_image_w_emojis = emoji_image_creator.generate_and_add_to_img(
        xy_coords=(200, 300),
        base_image=base_image_w_emojis,
        emoji_prompt=":smiling_face_with_halo:",
        tar_width=100)

    base_image_w_emojis = emoji_image_creator.generate_and_add_to_img(
        xy_coords=(400, 200),
        base_image=base_image_w_emojis,
        emoji_prompt=":dog_face:",
        tar_height=200,
        angle=-90)
    
    # this emoji will be skewed!
    base_image_w_emojis = emoji_image_creator.generate_and_add_to_img(
        xy_coords=(200, 0),
        base_image=base_image_w_emojis,
        emoji_prompt=":woozy_face:",
        tar_height=200,
        tar_width=50,
        angle=-90)

    base_image_w_emojis.save("example.png", format="png")
```

Which returns (the :woozy_face: is deliberately skewed):

[image]

Code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Emoji to image converter.

The code below allows to easily add emojis to an image, where each emoji can be
individually scaled in size and rotated. Note: Code was written using noto-emojis,
which are available under the Apache 2.0 license. Link to font repo:
https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-emoji/tree/main
"""
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Optional, Tuple

from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw
import emoji


class EmojiImageCreator:
    """Provides methods to create images of emojis and paste them on another image.
    
    This class uses a trick to dynamically create emoji images by writing the emoji
    as a text on a transparent base image. The class automatically detects the required
    base image size (lest the emoji could be cropped off on a base image that is too small),
    where the effective emoji size is regulated by the `size` parameter specified by the user.
    """

    def __init__(self, emoji_font_fp: str) -> None:
        """Class instantiation.
        
        Args:
            emoji_font_fp: String filepath pointing to emoji font which should be
                used.
        """
        # str: emoji-alias, as defined here: https://www.webfx.com/tools/emoji-cheat-sheet/
        self.emoji_prompt: Optional[str] = None
        # str: emoji associated with emoji-alias
        self.emoji: Optional[str] = None

        self.emoji_font_fp = str(emoji_font_fp)
        assert Path(self.emoji_font_fp).is_file()

        # ImageFont.FreeTypeFont: emoji font to be used to generate the emoji images
        self.font = self.get_font()

    def generate_emoji(self,
                       emoji_prompt: str,
                       tar_width: Optional[int] = None,
                       tar_height: Optional[int] = None,
                       angle: int = 0) -> Image.Image:
        """Generates an emoji image.

        Args:
            emoji_prompt: Emoji-alias associated with a certain emoji. E.g.
                `:thumbs_up:` is ``. See: https://www.webfx.com/tools/emoji-cheat-sheet/
            tar_width: Target width as number of pixels. User can specify target
                width and/or target height.
            tar_height: Target height as number of pixels.
            angle (optional): Angle by which image should be rotated.

        Returns:
            Generated emoji image.
        """
        self.set_params(emoji_prompt=emoji_prompt)

        emoji_img = self.emoji_to_image()

        emoji_img = EmojiImageCreator.scale_image(img=emoji_img,
                                                  tar_width=tar_width,
                                                  tar_height=tar_height)

        emoji_img = EmojiImageCreator.rotate_image(img=emoji_img, angle=angle)

        return emoji_img

    def generate_and_add_to_img(self,
                                base_image: Image.Image,
                                xy_coords: Tuple[int, int],
                                emoji_prompt: str,
                                tar_width: Optional[int] = None,
                                tar_height: Optional[int] = None,
                                angle: int = 0) -> Image.Image:
        """Generates an emoji image.

        Args:
            base_image: Image on which generated emoji should be added.
            xy_coords: Coordinates on base_image should be added (xy values represent
                top right corner of the pasted emoji).
            emoji_prompt: Emoji-alias associated with a certain emoji. E.g.
                `:thumbs_up:` is ``. See: https://www.webfx.com/tools/emoji-cheat-sheet/
            tar_width: Target width as number of pixels. User can specify target
                width and/or target height.
            tar_height: Target height as number of pixels.
            angle (optional): Angle by which image should be rotated.

        Returns:
            Generated emoji image.
        """
        emoji_img = self.generate_emoji(emoji_prompt=emoji_prompt,
                                        tar_width=tar_width,
                                        tar_height=tar_height,
                                        angle=angle)

        base_image.paste(emoji_img, xy_coords, mask=emoji_img)

        return base_image

    def set_params(self, emoji_prompt: str) -> None:
        """Sets instance attributes required to generate emoji images.
        
        Args:
            emoji_prompt: Emoji-alias associated with a certain emoji. E.g.
                `:thumbs_up:` is ``. See: https://www.webfx.com/tools/emoji-cheat-sheet/
        """
        self.emoji_prompt = emoji_prompt
        self.emoji = EmojiImageCreator.prompt_to_emoji(
            emoji_prompt=emoji_prompt)

    def get_font(self) -> ImageFont.FreeTypeFont:
        """Method loading font specified during class instantiation.

        Note: Font size is hardcoded given that `NotoColorEmoji.tff` only works
        with the specified size. For more info see:
        `https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/6166`.

        Returns:
            Emoji font.
        """
        return ImageFont.truetype(font=self.emoji_font_fp,
                                  size=109,
                                  encoding='unic')

    @classmethod
    def prompt_to_emoji(cls, emoji_prompt: str) -> str:
        """Converts a emoji prompt to it's respective symbol.

        Args:
            emoji_prompt: Emoji-alias associated with a certain emoji. E.g.
                `:thumbs_up:` is ``. See: https://www.webfx.com/tools/emoji-cheat-sheet/
        
        Returns:
            Emoji symbol associated with prompt.
        """
        return emoji.emojize(emoji_prompt)

    def get_emoji_dimensions(self) -> Tuple[int, int]:
        """Calculates the width and height of the emoji.

        Note: This information allows to dynamically create the transparent
        base image on which the emoji will appear as a text. Since the emoji should
        exactly fit the base image, the dimensions of each base image needs to
        depend on the emoji that will be written on it.

        Returns:
            width: Effective width of emoji, given hardcoded font size.
            height: Effective height of emoji, given hardcoded font size.
        """
        assert isinstance(
            self.emoji,
            str), "Parameters not set; call `.set_params()` priorly."

        left, top, right, bottom = self.font.getbbox(self.emoji)
        width, height = right - left, bottom - top

        return width, height

    def emoji_to_image(self) -> Image.Image:
        """Converts emoji to an image by writing it as a text on a transparent image.
        
        Returns:
            Image of emoji.
        """
        assert isinstance(
            self.emoji,
            str), "Parameters not set; call `.set_params()` priorly."

        emoji_width, emoji_height = self.get_emoji_dimensions()

        base_img = Image.new(mode='RGBA',
                             size=(emoji_width, emoji_height),
                             color=(0, 0, 0, 0))

        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(base_img)
        draw.text(xy=(0, 0),
                  text=self.emoji,
                  font=self.font,
                  embedded_color=True)

        return base_img

    @classmethod
    def scale_image(cls,
                    img: Image.Image,
                    tar_width: Optional[int] = None,
                    tar_height: Optional[int] = None) -> Image.Image:
        """Scales image to user-specified size.

        Allows for specifying target width and/or target height to which image
        should be scaled.

        Args:
            img: Target image to scale
            tar_width: Target width as number of pixels. User can specify target
                width and/or target height.
            tar_height: Target height as number of pixels.
        
        Returns:
            Scaled image.
        """
        width, height = img.size

        if tar_width and not tar_height:
            width_scale = tar_width / width
            height_to_scale = int(height * width_scale)

            return img.resize((tar_width, height_to_scale))

        if tar_height and not tar_width:
            height_scale = tar_height / height
            width_to_scale = int(width * height_scale)

            return img.resize((width_to_scale, tar_height))

        if tar_width and tar_height:
            return img.resize((tar_width, tar_height))

        raise ValueError(
            "Either `tar_width` or `tar_height` must be specified!")

    @classmethod
    def rotate_image(cls, img: Image.Image, angle: int) -> Image.Image:
        """Rotates image using user-specified angle.

        Args:
            img: Target image to scale
            angle: Angle by which image should be rotated.

        Returns:
            Rotated image.
        """
        return img.rotate(angle, expand=True)
```